# Why is my Python for loop remove() altering a variable declared prior to the loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a simplified version of my function that compares three sets of numbers and finds the two sets with the highest correlation:

```
inputs = ['vars_one', 'vars_two', 'vars_three']
def MostCorrelatedInputs(inputs):
    correlation = 0
    saved_inputs = inputs
    for i in inputs:
        testlist = saved_inputs
        testlist.remove(i)
        new_correlation = FindCorrelation(testlist)
        if new_correlation > correlation:
            correlation = new_correlation
            outputs = testlist
    return outputs
```

The issue is, when I run the function, it seems that the `remove()` function alters the saved_inputs variable, even though I'm calling it on `inputs`. Is this an issue with garbage collection? Why is the saved_inputs variable getting altered by my for loop, and if `remove()` is expected to alter this variable, is there a better method of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you a hint:

```
>>>a = [1,2,3]
>>>b = a
>>>b.remove(1)
>>>a
[2, 3]
```

It's because `b` references the same object as `a` does! If you remove something from `b` you are removing it from the object that `a` references as well. To change this, as in create a copy, do

```
>>>b = a[:]
>>>b.remove(1)
>>>a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>b
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Wow - obviously a learning about how Python works, thank you!

Comment: @YPCrumble you're welcome, it's a very common mistake. Here's something that looks like a good read: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Answer (score 1):

So when you do a :

```
saved_inputs = inputs
```

and

```
testlist = saved_inputs
```

Both testlist and saved_inputs references the same object/list - inputs.

You need to get something like a "deep copy" of the list. i-e

To quote your example code:

```
testlist = saved_inputs

testlist.remove('vars_one')

print testlist
print saved_inputs
```

This would result in:

```
['vars_two', 'vars_three']
['vars_two', 'vars_three']
```

You have to do something like this:

```
testlist = list(saved_inputs)

testlist.remove('vars_one')

print testlist
print saved_inputs
```

To get the result:

```
['vars_two', 'vars_three']
['vars_one', 'vars_two', 'vars_three']
```

Which i think is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring testlist to reference the same reference as inputs.

So if you want to make testlist contain just the values and not the reference, you would need to do the following for a list:

```
inputlist = inputs[:]
```